# Adding PFUser as Pointer Value with Swift

Tags: ios, database, swift, parse-platform, ios8

I have a table view that lists all the users in my app. When one of my logged in users taps on one of these users, I want to add that user to his "friends" (which is a class) My `Friends` class has 2 main columns: the `user` column (the one who added the friend) that points to the `PFUser` class, and the `friend` column, (the one who was added) which also points to the `PFUser` class. I query the `User` table to find a user that matches the username that the table view cell shows. However, when I try to add the results of this query to the friend column in the Friends class, I get an error that says, `"Error: invalid type for key friend, expected *_User, but got array"` Anyway, here is my code: (Array Userlist is an array that stores all the users returned from the database)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:    NSIndexPath) {

    var user:PFUser = userList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFUser
    var username = user.username

    var friendQuery = PFUser.query()
    friendQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
    var friends = friendQuery.findObjects()

    for person in friends{
    var friend = PFObject(className: "Friends")
    friend.addObject(PFUser.currentUser(), forKey: "user")
    friend.addObject(person, forKey: "friend")
    friend.saveInBackground()

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

if "Friends" "user" col is pointer in parse.com  -> Can you try my code

```
for person in friend{
var friend = PFObject(classname: "Friends")
friend["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
friend["friend"] = person as PFObject  // col type have to POINTER
friend.save()  //use save()
}
```